# Python thinks json is a local variable

Tags: json, variables, scope, local

This function is supposed to manipulate values in a dictionary stored as a file. I am getting

> "local variable 'json' referenced before assignment"

on the fourth line, "dictio = json.loads()."

I have imported json, in fact the function below this runs perfectly well performing almost the same task. Unlike the later function, this one is also throwing an empty queue error, even though I have not intentionally asked for multithreading.

```
def updateTally(lefty):                                          #Tally records responses to each question
    global num, total, thisQ 
    rf = open("20QTally.json", "r")
    dictio = json.loads(rf.read())
    rf.close()

    dictio[str(0)] += 1
    total = dictio[str(0)]
    if lefty == 1:
        dictio[str(num)] +=1
    thisQ = dictio[str(num)]

    json = json.dumps(dictio)
    wf = open("20QTally.json", "w")
    wf.write(json)
    wf.close()
```

def record_score(score):                                        # Opens, reads, writes, and closes the score file, 20QScores.txt (filename)
    global total
    scoref = open(filename, "r")                                # Records and reports individuals' responses
    sf = json.loads(scoref.read())                              # Json helps with string and integer writing and reading to files.
    key = str(score) 
    if key in sf:
        sf[key] += 1
    else:
        sf[key] = 1 #etc.

Answer (score 5):

you are trying to assign value to `json` here

```
json = json.dumps(dictio)
```

change the variable name

Comment: Amazing! That is code I borrowed from somewhere. This change fixed both problems (I see now how the queue was being invoked now.) The error was coming on a different line, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Just as an extra quirk - I was getting the same thing and was really confused since I wasn't declaring any variables named `json`, however; I think some sort of autocomplete or GitHub CoPilot or something like that had previously declared a variable named `json` and it was in a block of code that came _after_ my `return` statement, and thus VS Code had it greyed out and my brain just completely ignored that it was there. So Python will still throw an error in code that is unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

Its's because you are shadowing the `json` module declaring variable with the  same name. Just don't do that, get some name that is unique within the scope.